# CSS techniques to make squares float in a grid while filling a parent container's width

Tags: css, layout, css-float

So I have a page for displaying products, and I'm trying to convert that page from a table-based layout where each spot is a table cell, three to a row, into a dynamic grid of some sort.
Unfortunately, using inline-block is a pain due to the "keep whitespace like it matters between inline-block" issue, and using floats is... ok, but tends to result in gaps in the listings (see attached image).
[image: floats are a problem]

The tiles have a max and min width, so it seems like waterfall or pinterest type tiling *shouldn't* necessary, since I'm not really dealing with variable-height and width rectangles.

So what *techniques* are best for making this kind of grid listing fill available space regularly, but still allow rows to be shorter for shorter screens?

There's an in-development example of the problem page here: http://www.shermanbrothers.com/catalog.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the technique is called Liquid design or if you have to support smart phones and tablets, then it will be "Responsive design".

In your scenario, first you need to turn the fixed-width table to a liquid grid. The code snippets are:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjm66/)

**CSS:**

```
       * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;

}


.container {
    width: auto;
}

    .container:after {
        content: " ";
        clear: both;
        display: table;
    }


.tabletContainer {
    /*The total width for the first two column*/
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
}



.left {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    /*Each column takes have of the container size, so their width =67/2 = 33.5%*/
    width: 50%;
}

.middle {
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    /*Each column takes have of the container size, so their width =67/2 = 33.5%*/
    width: 50%;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    background-color: blue;
}

/*For tablet devices, show only the two columns in a row and a column underneath*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
    .tabletContainer, .right {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
    }

  .right
  {
      clear: both;
      width: 50%;
  }
}


/*For mobile phones, show only one column*/
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .tabletContainer, .left, .right, .middle {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
       display: block;
    }




}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="tabletContainer">


            <div class="left">It is well enough that people of the nation do not understand our banking and monetary system, for if they did, I believe there would be a revolution before tomorrow morning.
            </div>
            <div class="middle">Under capitalism, man exploits man. Under communism, it's just the opposite.
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="right">One of the funny things about the stock market is that every time one person buys, another sells, and both think they are astute
        </div>
    </div>
```

1. You also need to make your images liquid as well. One trick is to remove the fixed-widths and heights of your images.

**CSS**

```
/*Make images not resize outside of the column that they are in*/
img {
    max-width: 100%;    
}
```

**HTML**

```
<img src="imgs/clouds.jpg" alt="Clouds" class="half right"/>
```

You can also change the image size by using %. For instance, the width of the image in the example above will be set to 50% of the container width by using the following CSS.

```
img.half {
    max-width: 50%; 
}
```

If you want to float it to the left of the container:

```
img.left {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

By applying padding/margins you can achieve the effect you want.

Hope this help.